# Program to show keystrokes (shortcuts) on display

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, application

I'm going to make a presentation about a software product and it has some key shortcuts, that I want to show. Is there a program, which displays the keyboard-shortcuts, that I have used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a program called [key-mon](http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/) that monitors the pressed keys. It's been some time since I used it, but it worked well and it's display is quite appealing.

Comment: New link for it: https://github.com/scottkirkwood/key-mon

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xev` (X events) to do this.

Start the application you'd like to monitor, e.g., `xman &`.

Then, use `wmctrl -l` to list X windows. It could look like this:

```
0x00400009  0 VLAN-.... urxvt
0x00e0007a  0 VLAN-.... Iceweasel
0x00800011  0 VLAN-.... xman
```

You need the window (hex) ID in the first column; to get it, you could use `grep` and fetch the line by the fourth column (the application name, which is much more natural for you to use as a human) - when you have the line, you could get the first column with `cut` (the first field with `-f1`, using a whitespace delimiter `-d" "` to separate fields).

You could parse the data (to get the ID) in a number of ways, or even enter the ID manually, of course. (The zeroes in the second column above are the desktop number.)

Then, try

```
xev -id `wmctrl -l | grep xman | cut -d" " -f1` | tee event.txt
```

It will show the keystrokes (and more) in the same terminal as the command was invoked; plus, with `tee`, it'll store what you see in a file. It could be a good idea to let the output be shown on `stdout` in the terminal as this will show you instantly the action; also, if you don't run the command as a background process (with `&`), you can terminate it easily with `Ctrl-C.`

**NOTE** It works for urxvt and xman, but for some reason, it fails for Iceweasel in the above listing (it records something, but it isn't presenting key events as clear (by far) as is the case with those other examples.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [screenkey](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/screenkey) today, it is very cool and works very well.